# How I can sort images by dimension in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How I can sort images by dimension in JavaScript or jQuery. My code is following:

```
var imgsrc = '';
if (document.images.length < 1) {
    alert('No images to open');
    return;
}
for (var i = 0; i < window.parent.document.images.length; i++) {
    imgsrc + = '\n';
}

if (imgsrc != '') {
    var newwin = window.open('', '');
    newwin.document.open();
    newwin.document.write('\n' + imgsrc + '');
    newwin.document.close();
} else {
    alert('No images!')
}​
```

Please help me out. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript) for getting image dimensions. You can sort an array like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp). .sort() has an overload that takes a sort function. That is where you would compare the sizes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery:

```
​var images = $('img');

if ( images.length ) {
// images were found
 images.sort( function (img1, img2) { return img1.width - img2.width } );                                     
}
```

here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fNbQB/)